# Get all possible iterations of many arrays in php

Tags: php

I have few arrays for example:

```
array(
    'color' => array('red', 'blue', ...);
    'size' => array('small', 'big', ...);
    'temp' => array('hot', 'cold', ...);
     ...
)
```

Is there a function so I can get all possible iterations of these arrays ? (and more arrays and values if needed).
For example result should be:

```
array(
    0 => array('color'=> 'red', 'size'=>'small', 'temp'=>'hot')
    1 =>  array('color'=> 'red', 'size'=>'small', 'temp'=>'cold')
    2 =>  array('color'=> 'red', 'size'=>'big', 'temp'=>'hot')
    3 =>  array('color'=> 'red', 'size'=>'big', 'temp'=>'cold')
)
```

... and so on.

Comment: What type of an output are you seeking ?

Comment: array, i've updated the question

Comment: `(and more arrays if needed)` how are you planing to inject arrays to the wanted function. In you example they are predefined, are the all gonna be combined in 1 big array for example ?

Comment: If you change the values, your only add values to $color, $size and $temp arrays or your add more arrays that these three?

Comment: sorry for being not clear, i've updated the task once again. I can have many arrays and many values inside. I can have all these arrays inside one parent array like in the example above

Comment: you said you have "many" arrays like this.. I don't think there's a practical way to get this without you more than likely running out of memory. What do you *really* need from this, just how many combinations there are? Or perhaps ultimately a single array with randomly selected? What are you actually going to do with this if you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive approach:

```
function generateCombinations($array, $start = 0) {
    $size = count($array);
    if ($size == $start) {
        return array('');
    }
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array[$start] as $val) {
        foreach (generateCombinations($array, $start + 1, $size) as $last) {
            $result[] = $val . ' ' . $last;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$array = array(
    array('red', 'blue'), 
    array('small', 'big'),
    array('hot', 'cold')
);

$result = generateCombinations($array);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red small hot 
    [1] => red small cold 
    [2] => red big hot 
    [3] => red big cold 
    [4] => blue small hot 
    [5] => blue small cold 
    [6] => blue big hot 
    [7] => blue big cold 
)
```

[**Online Demo**](https://eval.in/128703)